# How to write into a Bootstrap div alert when a user fills out a form incorrectly?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get jQuery to validate if what the user imputed into a form was correct. I got the validation to work. But, every time I try displaying the errors to a div I wrote in my .php document it has issues. It will only display the errors for a few seconds when the button is clicked. What can I do?

Thanks in advance! Here's my code!

Jquery:

```
var errorMessage = "";

var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;

$("#emailSubmit").click( function () {


if ($('#bodyE').val() == '' ) {
    errorMessage += "<p>Body</p>";
}


if ($('#subject').val() == '') {
    errorMessage += "<p>Subject</p>";
}

if($('#email').val() == '') {
    errorMessage += "</p>Email Adress</p>";
} else {
    if (pattern.test($('#email').val()) == false) {
        errorMessage += "<p>Email not valid!</p>";
    }
}

if(errorMessage != '') {
 $(errorMessage).appendTo("#errorAlert");
}

});
```

the php/HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>
<title>PHP</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="php.css">


</head>



<body>

<?php 

$re = '/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i';

$errorMessage = "";


if(empty($_POST['body'])){

$errorMessage =  "<p>Body</p> " . $errorMessage;

    }


if(empty($_POST['subject'])){


$errorMessage = "<p>subject</p> " .$errorMessage  ;

}

if (empty(($_POST['email']))) {

$errorMessage =  "<p>Email Adress</p> " . $errorMessage;



}  else {


    if (preg_match($re, $_POST['email']) == false) { 

    $errorMessage = "<p>Email was not valid</p> " . $errorMessage;

}

} 




if ($errorMessage != is_null($errorMessage)){

//display error message

    echo  '<div class="container">
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<p><strong>Feild(s) Missing:</strong></p>
' . $errorMessage . '
</div>
</div>'; 

}

?>



<div class = "alert alert-danger" id="errorAlert"></div>



<form class="col-md-6 mx-auto" method="post">
    <h1>Send an email!</h1>

    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id=email name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bodyE">Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" id="bodyE" name="body"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-right">
        <button type="submit" id="emailSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="alert.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="php.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the

classes `.fade` and `.show`

to alert container, and also `.alert-dismissible`

to add the padding to container.

```
echo  '<div class="container">
         <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
           <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times; 
          </a>
         <p><strong>Field(s) Missing:</strong></p>
    ' . $errorMessage . '
       </div>
    </div>';
```